# Including an php which is including another php

Tags: include

I am new to php language but I need the include() function to separate my site into different PHPs in order to call it again on different pages.All worked fine until I came to include a PHP which includes another PHP . Here's the code in html file :

```
<?php
set_include_path('contents');
include 'index_page.php';
?>
```

index_page.php which includes sidebar.php :

```
<?php
echo
'<div class="body2">
   <div class="content">
   <h1>text</h1>
     <img src="images/homeimage.jpg">
     <p>some text</div> '. include "sidebar.php"; '</div>';
?>
```

sidebar.php:

```
<?php
echo
'<div id="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><div class="arrow-up"></div><a href="">اشترك معنا</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text</a></li>  
        <li><a href="">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>';
?>
```

The result that appears in the browser was that the sidebar.php was included before the text as if the code was like that :

```
<?php
echo
include "sidebar.php";.'<div class="body2">
   <div class="content">
   <h1>text</h1>
     <img src="images/homeimage.jpg">
     <p>some text</div> </div>';
?>
```

Any solutions ??